# Find all $n$ by $n$ matrices $A$ such that $A^2 = A.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

It isn't too hard to show that there are infinitely many non-invertible matrices, and finitely many invertible ones. But how do we find all the possible matrices?

Edit : The other question has not given all the matrices.

Comment: Observe that $x = Ax + (I-A)x$. Here $Ax$ is an element of the range of $A$ and $(I-A)x$ is and element of the kernel of $A$, since $A(I-A)x=(A-A^2)x=0$. Take a basis of the space formed as the union of a basis of the kernel of $A$ and a basis of the range of $A$. The action of $A$ on that basis is fixed. The elements of the kernel go to zero, the element of the range are fixed. Therefore, the matrix $A$ is determined by saying who is the kernel and a complement of the kernel to be its range. $A$ is the projection onto its range, parallel to its kernel.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos All the solutions aren't given in that question.

Comment: @orole edit : I don't understand much after we form the basis from the union.

Comment: Take any diagonalisable matrix with eigenvalues $0,1$. The blocks of a Jordan form must have size one.

Comment: @copper.hat How would we show that these are indeed all the solutions?

Comment: $A$ is the projection onto its range, parallel to its kernel. That is what $x=Ax+(I-A)x$, $AAx=Ax$ and $A(I-A)x=0$ shows. Therefore, the $A$ is determined by a choice of a subspace (which will be its kernel) and a complement of that subspace (to be its range). Once you choose kernel and range the whole matrix is determined and conversely.

Comment: The solution in the other question describes all such matrices.

Comment: @Saad: If it is not diagonalisable then the Jordan form has at least one block that has size greater than one in which case we must have $A^k \neq A^{k+1}$ for some $k$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term projection & parallel

Comment: @Saad It doesn't matter. You don't need to mention them. You only need to use use three trivial equalitites: $x=Ax+(I-A)x$, $AAx=Ax$ and $A(I-A)x=0$. The first one tells you that once you determine the range (the elements of the form $Ax$) and the kernel (the elements of the form $(I-A)x$) that determines the whole matrix. You know that $(I-A)x$ is the kernel due to the third equality. You know that the action of the matrix on its range is the identity due to the second equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $A$ is diagonalizable since the polynomial $x(x-1)$ annihilates it and then $\operatorname{sp}(A)\subset \{0,1\}$ with multiplicity $\dim\ker A$ and $\operatorname{rank}A=:r$ respectively so $A$ is similar to $D=\operatorname{diag}(\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{r\,\text{times}},0,\ldots,0)$, i.e.

$$A=PDP^{-1}$$
where $P$ is invertible.

Reciprocally, the matrix $A=PDP^{-1}$ verify $A^2=A$. Conclude.

Comment: Thanks. Could you reference me to a link where I can read more about the polynomial part? None of the terminology there is known to me

Comment: Matrix Analysis
By Roger A. Horn, Charles R. Johnson is a good reference.